# Change created order number

Tags: magento-1.7, entities, sales-order

I lost a few orders at Magento and I am recreating it manually, but I need to keep the old id. 
I do not have enough information to create all the lost orders, because this some orders id need to be skipped, because this I want to manually put the id of them.

I tried the mysql with the command:

```
update sales_flat_order set increment_id=100000180, entity_id=180 where entity_id=168;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THIS IS NO GOOD IDEA. PLAYING IN THE DATABASE IS ALWAYS A BAD IDEA**

I'm not sure, whether I understand your question, there is no question mark in it, but I'll try.

The next increment id for an order can be found here: `eav_entity_store` so change the value to the one you want to have for the next order/invoice/whatever - 1.

Then your way is correct, sort our what IDs your orders need and then change the `increment_id`s and the `entity_id`s.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I found this command:
UPDATE eav_entity_store SET increment_last_id = '100000160' WHERE entity_store_id = 1;

With this I can set the next order id. I'll record them and after return to the default.